# Delegation with value types in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

In my application I use to delegation: Controller `C` use delegation `D1` with a model item named `M1` and `M1` use delegation with another model item called `M2`.

Everything is fine when `M1` invoke delegate method from `C`.

```
C ---> M1
<----- delegation : OK
```

Everything is fine when `M2` invoke delegate method from `M1`.

```
M1 ---> M2
<------ delegation : OK
```

But when `M2` invoke delegate method from `M1` that in turn invoke delegate method from `C` this does not work.

```
C ---> M1 ---> M2
       <------ delegation
<------ delegation
```

Debugger revealed that value for delegate in `M1` is nil as it should be `C`.

### Update

```
protocol TestOneDelegate:class {

    func testMethodOne(message:String)

}

protocol TestTwoDelegate {

    func testMethodTwo(message:String)

}

//
struct M2 {

    var delegate:TestTwoDelegate?

    func testOperation() {
        delegate?.testMethodTwo(message:"From M2" )
    }
}


struct M1:TestTwoDelegate {

    weak var delegate:TestOneDelegate?
    var m2:M2

    init() {
        m2 = M2()
        m2.delegate = self
    }

    mutating func testOperation() {
        delegate?.testMethodOne(message: "From M1 - Start")

        // BREAKPOINT 1
        m2.testOperation()

        delegate?.testMethodOne(message: "From M1 - End")

    }

    /// Implementation of TestTwoDelegate
    func testMethodTwo(message:String) {

        // BREAKPOINT 2
        print ("M1 get message from M2: " + message)
        delegate?.testMethodOne(message: message + " via M1")
    }

}


class TestControler:UIViewController,TestOneDelegate {

    var m1:M1!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        m1 = M1()
        m1.delegate = self
        m1.testOperation()
    }

    /// Implementation of TestOneDelegate
    func testMethodOne(message:String) {
        print ("Controller get following message from M1: " + message)
    }


}
```

Expected results:

```
Controller get following message from M1: From M1 - Start
M1 get message from M2: From M2
Controller get following message from M1: From M2 via M1  
Controller get following message from M1: From M1 - End
```

Obtained results:

```
Controller get following message from M1: From M1 - Start
M1 get message from M2: From M2
Controller get following message from M1: From M1 - End
```

There is the `From M2 via M1` missing...

Stop on 'BREAKPOINT 1', `delegate` have a value.
Stop on 'BREAKPOINT 2', `delegate` is nil.

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you provide delegation functions and instances?

Comment: There's no limit, it's just a bug in your code.

Comment: "Delegation" is not a thing. What you are using here is properties and protocols. The only thing that makes it a "delegate" is the name of he property you are using. And, no, there is no limit to how far down you can pass a property. If I pass a string to a class I can then pass that same string to another class and another and so on.

Comment: @JuicyFruit Ok, I have to extract code from my project to create a sample. Give me a few time!

Comment: For some reason this post has me wanting to make a delegate loop with a 2 second delay that calls itself infinitely between the same two view controllers. The only possible thing that could actually implement this without being stupid is some form of animation.... hmmmmmm

Comment: It's not a problem of delegating, but just a problem of value types. Try changing `struct M1` to `class M1`, and check what you get.

Comment: @OOPer Changing `struct M1` to `class M1` make it work. Thank you. Now I want to understand the situation. Can you explain me where the problem lie with value types? Where I am wrong?

Comment: When assignment of value type, the instance is copied, and the copy is assigned. So, The instances in `TestControler.m1` and `m2.delegate` are two different instances. Generally, value type (`struct`) does not fit for delegate pattern.

Comment: @OOPer Ok, thank you. Is an answer to this is to _propagate_ the `delegate` by updating `m2.delegate` when `m1.delegate` is set?

Comment: In your code, `m2.delegate = self` is creating a copy of `M1`, so, setting the delegate of `M1` before that line can be another solution. Declare an initializer of `M1` as `init(delegate:  TestOneDelegate)` and put `self.delegate = delegate` before `m2.delegate = self`.

Comment: @OOPer Ok, Thank you. Now the problem is solve, would you write an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139413/discussion-between-domsware-and-ooper).

Comment: I think you have understand why this issue happens, and how to solve it. Please take some time to write an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by @OOper

With value types assignment create a copy of the instance. So in `M1.init()`, `m2.delegate = self` create a copy of the instance then assign it to `m2.delegate`. Thus any modification done to the instance of M1 is not reflected to `m2.delegate` and `m2.delegate`is `nil`.

Part related to *Classes and Structures* of *The Swift Programming Language* quote:

> As a general guideline, consider creating a structure when one or more of these conditions apply:
>   ...
>   - Any properties stored by the structure are themselves value types, which would also be expected to be copied rather than referenced.

So best answer to this question is to use `class` instead of `struct` when delegation is needed.

For curiosity purpose here follows two answers to the initial problem still using `struct`. Be aware these solutions only work in the scope of this example. If controller access properties of `m1` then problems may comes.

Let's say `testMethodTwo` now modify `m1` properties:

```
func testMethodTwo(message:String) {

    // Properties are modify here
    // BREAKPOINT 2
    print ("M1 get message from M2: " + message)
    delegate?.testMethodOne(message: message + " via M1")
}
```

Then when it's method `testMethodOne` is invoke controller won't see these modifications on `m1` as they occured on a distinct copy of `m1`.

### 1. Initialize with delegate

```
struct M1:TestTwoDelegate {

    var m2 = M2()
    weak var delegate:TestOneDelegate?


    init(delegate:TestOneDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        m2.delegate = self
    }
```

### 2. Propagate update

```
struct M1:TestTwoDelegate {

    var m2 = M2()

    weak var delegate:TestOneDelegate? {
        didSet {
            m2.delegate = self
        }
    }
```